# Calling function on valid values of masked arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy masked arrays:

```
>>> x
masked_array(data = [1 2 -- 4],
             mask = [False False  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
>>> y
masked_array(data = [4 -- 0 4],
             mask = [False  True False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

If I try to divide `x` by `y`, the division operation is not actually performed when one of the operands is masked, so I don't get a divide-by-zero error.

```
>>> x/y
masked_array(data = [0.25 -- -- 1.0],
             mask = [False  True  True False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

This even works if I define my own division function, `div`:

```
>>> def div(a,b):
    return a/b

>>> div(x, y)
masked_array(data = [0.25 -- -- 1.0],
             mask = [False  True  True False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

However, if I wrap my function with `vectorize`, the function is called on masked values and I get an error:

```
>>> np.vectorize(div)(x, y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1811, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1880, in _vectorize_call
    outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
  File "<input>", line 2, in div
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Is there a way I can call a function with array arguments, and have the function only be executed when all of the arguments are unmasked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The problem

Calling the function directly worked because, when you call `div(x,y)`, `div`'s arguments `a` and `b` become the MaskedArrays `x` and `y`, and the resulting code for `a/b` is `x.__div__(y)` (or `__truediv__`).

Now, since `x` is a MaskedArray, it has the intelligence to perform the division on another MaskedArray, following its rules.

However, when you vectorize it, your `div` function is not going to see any MaskedArrays, just scalars, a couple of `int`s in this case.  So, when it tries `a/b` in the third items, it will be 'something' by zero, and you get  the error.

MaskedArray's implementation seems to be based on re-implementing much of Numpy specifically for MaskedArrays.  See, for example, that you have both `numpy.log` and `numpy.ma.log`.  Compare running both of them on a MaskedArray that contains negative values.  Both actually return a proper MaskedArray, but the plain numpy version also outputs some complains about dividing by zero:

```
In [116]: x = masked_array(data = [-1, 2, 0, 4],
     ...:              mask = [False, False,  True, False],
     ...:        fill_value = 999999)

In [117]: numpy.log(x)
/usr/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  #!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[117]: 
masked_array(data = [-- 0.6931471805599453 -- 1.3862943611198906],
             mask = [ True False  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [118]: numpy.ma.log(x)
Out[118]: 
masked_array(data = [-- 0.6931471805599453 -- 1.3862943611198906],
             mask = [ True False  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

If you run the numpy.log version on a plain list, it will return `nan` and `inf` for invalid values, not throw an error like the `ZeroDivisionError` you're getting.

```
In [138]: a = [1,-1,0]

In [139]: numpy.log(a)
/usr/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  #!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[139]: array([  0.,  nan, -inf])
```

## Simpler solution

With that, I see two alternatives: first, for the simpler case you listed, you could replace the bad values by a no-op: 1 in `div`'s case (note that the data is slightly different from yours, as there is a zero you didn't mark as masked):

```
x = masked_array(data = [1, 2, 0, 4],
             mask = [False, False,  True, False],
       fill_value = 999999)
y = masked_array(data = [4, 0, 0, 4],
             mask = [False,  True, True, False],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [153]: numpy.vectorize(div)(x,y.filled(1))
Out[153]: 
masked_array(data = [0.25 2.0 -- 1.0],
             mask = [False False  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

The problem with that approach is that the filled values are listed as non-masked on the result, which is probably not what you want.

## Better solution

Now, `div` was probably just an example, and you probably want more complex behavior for which there is not a 'no-op' argument.  In this case, you can do as Numpy did for `log`, and avoid throwing an exception, instead returning a specific value.  In this case, `numpy.ma.masked`.  `div`'s implementation becomes this:

```
In [154]: def div(a,b):
     ...:     try:
     ...:         return a/b
     ...:     except Exception as e:
     ...:         warnings.warn (str(e))
     ...:         return numpy.ma.masked
     ...:     
     ...:         

In [155]: numpy.vectorize(div)(x,y)
/usr/bin/ipython:5: UserWarning: division by zero
  start_ipython()
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2813:     UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  res = array(outputs, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
Out[155]: 
masked_array(data = [0.25 -- -- 1.0],
             mask = [False  True  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

## More generic solution

But perhaps you already have the function and do not want to change it, or it is third-party.  In that case, you could use a higher-order function:

```
In [164]: >>> def div(a,b):
     ...:     return a/b
     ...: 

In [165]: def masked_instead_of_error (f):
     ...:     def wrapper (*args, **kwargs):
     ...:         try:
     ...:             return f(*args, **kwargs)
     ...:         except:
     ...:             return numpy.ma.masked
     ...:     return wrapper
     ...:        

In [166]: numpy.vectorize(masked_instead_of_error(div))(x,y)
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2813:             UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  res = array(outputs, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
Out[166]: 
masked_array(data = [0.25 -- -- 1.0],
             mask = [False  True  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

On the implementations above, using warnings might or might not be a good idea.  You may also want to restrict the types of exceptions you'll be catching for returning `numpy.ma.masked`.

Note also that `masked_instead_of_error` is ready to be used as a decorator for your functions, so you do not need to use it every time.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response.  It's helped my understanding of what's going on here.  Rather than pass the invalid values into my function, I would like to prevent the function from being called with masked values.  I adapted your decorator approach to come up with the following: https://gist.github.com/dbaston/b41c3fa8c02ac151e52e132509c89b4c

Comment: @dbaston, glad to have helped.  I found your solution very interesting.  Only thing that I'd point is that I think the last argument to `np.ma.where` should call `fn`, not `vectorized`, no?

Comment: I can't call `fn` directly if it contains `if` statements or other conditional logic.